# File upload size restriction on Safari browser for MAC - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, mac-os-x

**Problem** : I am trying to upload a file of size 50 Mb plus in SharePoint 2013 document library on Safari browser using MAC but getting error.
File size less than 50 Mb getting uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your SharePoint uploaded file size is limited to 50MB. Please increase file upload size . Check below steps

Central Administration >>Manage Web Applications>>
Select desired web application row (don’t click on the title, just select)
“General Settings”

in the ribbon
Under Maximum Upload Size, change the setting to the desired value (e.g. 200 MB in our example)

“OK”

Comment: Actually we are getting problem for Safari browser only on MAC machine. On windows for all browsers we are able to upload upto 250MB as per our configuration setting. On MAC machine for chrome and Firefox that is also working fine. Only for Safari browser we are facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using drag and drop for large files and instead use the upload option via the ribbon. It appears that only Chrome, Firefox and IE are recommended browsers for [drag and drop in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/dragging-files-using-web-browser).